# LINQ to JSON selection of certain elements

Tags: .net, json, linq

I have the following JSON:

```
{"response":[2939,
{"mid":6581,"date":1345018696,"out":0,"uid":84175314,"read_state":1,"title":" ... ","body":"Text1"},
{"mid":6578,"date":1344984256,"out":0,"uid":32438192,"read_state":1,"title":" ... ","body":"Text2"}
]}
```

Using the Newtonsoft JSON library, I need to select only this part (and then add the data to my object)

`{"mid":6581,"date":1345018696,"out":0,"uid":84175314,"read_state":1,"title":" ... ","body":"Text1"},
    {"mid":6578,"date":1344984256,"out":0,"uid":32438192,"read_state":1,"title":" ... ","body":"Text2"}`

(There are more than 2 elements in the source JSON)

I've written the following so far:

```
JObject jRes = JObject.Parse(json);
JArray jAr = (JArray)jRes["response"];

var query =
                    from msg in jAr
                    select new 
                    {
                        mid = (int)jAr["mid"],
                        date = (int)jAr["date"],
                        outt = (short)jAr["out"],
                        uid = (int)jAr["uid"],
                        read_state = (short)jAr["read_state"],
                        title = (string)jAr["title"],
                        body = (string)jAr["body"],
                    };
```

I'd like to restrict the query to to skip the first object in the array but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by 'create restriction'. Can you explain your problem a little more?

Comment: i meant how to skip the first object in the array - numeric type
(and in the long term for all data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from msg in jAr
            where  !(msg is JValue)
            select new
            {
                mid = (int)msg["mid"],
                date = (int)msg["date"],
                outt = (short)msg["out"],
                uid = (int)msg["uid"],
                read_state = (short)msg["read_state"],
                title = (string)msg["title"],
                body = (string)msg["body"],
            };
```