# Deserializing an array with json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, windows-phone

I need to deserialize a json array:

```
{"response":
[19,
    {"mid":1068,
     "date":1343848664,
     "out":1,
     "uid":44852633,
     "read_state":1,
     "title":" ... ",
     "body":"А я вовсю."},
    {"mid":1007,
     "date":1328782448,
     "out":1,
     "uid":16098752,
     "read_state":0,
     "title":" ... ",
     "body":"http:\/\/theantidj.net\/wp-content\/themes\/theantidjnet\/images\/khubvio.php"}
```

and so on. I'm using json.net. Can I perform deserealization using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()? And if so what classes should I create?

Comment: Is this a homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006795/linq-to-json-selection-of-certain-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another solution.

```
var itemList = ((JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json))["response"]
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(x.ToString()))
                .ToList();


public class Item
{
    public int mid { set; get; }
    public string date { set; get; }
    public int @out { set; get; }
    public int  uid { set; get; }
    public int read_state { set; get; }
    public string title { set; get; }
    public string body { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

L.B. provided the solution. But i would notice if my memory serves me well that **JObject** is used for *dynamic* types. Thus it requires **.Net 4** or higher. Just in case.

Comment: Oleg, JObject is a class that provides some methods like `jObj["property"]`. Using it with `dynamic` is a cosmetic style.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring)` after you define this `RootObject`.

The tool I use is http://json2csharp.com where you simply put in JSON and get out a corresponding object. You will want to make sure your JSON is well formed though, since in its current form it is not parsing.

Comment: Do you think this class `public class RootObject
{
    public List<object> response { get; set; }
}` generated by  `http://json2csharp.com` is useful ? See the link in my comment. The problem with this json is: it returns an array where one element is `19` and the other is object `{"mid":1068,
     "date":1343848664,
     "out":1,
     "uid":44852633,
     "read_state":1,
     "title":" ... ",
     "body":"А я вовсю."}`

Comment: Yes, the problem is with this number. So deserialization won't help here and I need to use Linq to Json?